# I have made a calculator with C++, but my request for the "type of calculator" loops twice. Can someone help point out my mistake?

Tags: c++, calculator

I am new to c++, just recently picked it up and I thought I would try making something to see the results of my studies. I plan on making a calculator with multiple functions, (hopefully) which eventually may include functions such as graphing equations and more difficult calculations.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



//CALCULATOR



//Functions
int chooseCal();
float getOp();
float getOpAd();
float userInput();
float normCal(float x, float ops, float y);



float getOp() //ask for operator input
{
    cout << "Enter an operator: " << endl;
    cout << "1. + (Addition) \n";
    cout << "2. - (Subtraction) \n";
    cout << "3. * (Multiplication) \n";
    cout << "4. / (Division) \n";
    cout << "5. ^ (Indices) \n";
    cout << "6. -^ (Root) \n";
    cout << "7. ! (Factorial) \n";

    float ops;
    cin >> ops;

    return ops;
}

float getOpAd()//ask for operator (Advanced Cal)
{
    cout << "Enter an operator: " << endl;
    cout << "1. Denery ==> Binary" << endl;
    cout << "2. Binary ==> Denery" << endl;
    cout << "3. Denery ==> Hexadecimal" << endl;
    cout << "4. Hexadecimal ==> Denery" << endl;

    float ops;
    cin >> ops;

    return ops;
}

int chooseCal()
{
    cout << "Which calculator would you like to use? " << endl;
    cout << "1. Normal \n";
    cout << "2. Computational \n";

    int chooseC;
    cin >> chooseC;

    return chooseC;
}

float userInput() //ask for number input
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";

    float userInput;
    cin >> userInput;

    return userInput;
}

//Calculators
float normCal(float x, float ops, float y) //Basic
{
    if (ops == 1)
        return x + y;
    if (ops == 2)
        return x - y;
    if (ops == 3)
        return x * y;
    if (ops == 4)
        return x / y;
    if (ops == 5)
        return pow(x, y);
    if (ops == 6)
        return pow(x, 1 / y);
}


//prints result
void result(float result)
{
    cout << "= " << result << endl;
}



//main()
int main()
{
    int chooseC = chooseCal();

    float ops;
    if (chooseCal() == 1)
        ops = getOp();
    else
        ops = getOpAd();

    float input1 = userInput();
    float input2 = userInput();

    float results = normCal(input1, ops, input2);
    result(results);

    return 0;
}
```

I have not yet coded for the "Computational" part of my calculator, but when I test the "Normal" calculator the request for either "Normal" or "Computational" repeats itself twice before moving on to showing the options to choose the operator. Can someone help point out where I have went wrong?

Comment: how many times to you call `chooseCal()` in your main function?

Comment: Why are you accepting the `op` as a `float` (`float ops`)? It should be an `enum` or a `char` or really anything but a float

Comment: if (chooseCal() == 1) should be replaced with chooseC

Comment: For almost all menus you have, you ask for integer input, and store it in a `float`. Why?

Comment: maybe it asks for it twice because you call it twice? `int chooseC = chooseCal()` and `if (chooseCal() == 1)`

Answer (score 3):

The first call to the `chooseCal()` function is in the following statement:

```
int chooseC = chooseCal();
```

The second is in the following `if` statement:

```
if (chooseCal() == 1)
```

Just because the function is used in a condition doesn't mean it doesn't get executed. It does. Here you probably meant:

```
if (chooseC == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is something I was unaware of